# redis-server.exe: cannot execute binary file in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I'm trying to deploy my Django app with Redis on Heroku, but it didn't work and got the error in logs.

I installed Redis for windows from [here](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases/tag/v5.0.9).

This is my `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
worker: bash Redis/redis-server.exe
```

My logs:

```
2020-12-04T01:56:26.263759+00:00 app[worker.1]: Redis/redis-server.exe: Redis/redis-server.exe: cannot execute binary file
2020-12-04T01:56:26.346545+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 126
2020-12-04T01:56:26.735800+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Heroku version

```
heroku/7.47.3 win32-x64 node-v12.16.2
```

I'm using windows and I'm pretty sure that my system type is 64bit operation system. What's wrong with my app? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using windows and I'm pretty sure that my system type is 64bit operation system

*You* might be, but *Heroku* isn't.

[Heroku stacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) are based on Ubuntu Linux or Docker. You won't be able to run Windows binaries on Heroku.

Based on your `Procfile`, it looks like you are trying to run a Redis server:

```
worker: bash Redis/redis-server.exe
```

This goes against Heroku's architecture. Instead, use [an appropriate add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). At the moment there are at least five officially-supported options:

- Redis To Go
- Redis Cloud
- openredis
- RedisGreen
- Heroku Redis

Take a look at their offerings, pick one, and provision it. At least some of these have free tiers.

You'll find instructions for connecting in the respective documentation, but generally each addon will set [a config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), which is really just an environment variable. For example, Redis To Go sets `REDISTOGO_URL`, which you can [access from your application code](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo#using-from-python) like this:

```py
import os
import redis

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
redis = redis.from_url(redis_url)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried heroku-redis instead. I finally connected myapp with redis. But it caused the following error which had been solved by executing redis-server.exe. WebSocket connection to 'my app' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: Ok. I want to make sure the one thing before accepting it. Is it impossible to execute redis-server like this way? @Chris

Comment: @zrdaisuke., it is impossible to run Windows binaries on Heroku, including the Windows version of Redis. Shipping a Linux binary is unlikely to work either, since web dynos are only allowed to expose a single port: the one that accepts HTTPS requests. You can't listen on a second port, e.g. to accept connections for Redis. Furthermore, dynos are meant to be disposable. They get restarted all the time, and you probably don't want your data store to lose data every day. Plus, doing it the Heroku way means you can trivially scale to multiple dynos.

Comment: Thank you for your kind replies. I will focus on how to debug another issue. @Chris